# Continue typing after inserting character with jQuery .keydown()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, input

I have a simple input that adds the character "@" automatically once I start typing. I have everything I need so far with jQuery using the .keydown() function, but once the character "@" is inserted, I cannot continue typing.

How to make it so I can continue typing after the @?

```
let input = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-input");

$("input").keydown(function(){
    $(input).val("@");
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account that the first character will always be an @, you can check if it exists

```
$('.custom-input').on('keydown', function() {
    // custom-input reference
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val().charAt(0) === '@') {
        return;
    } else {
        $(this).val('@' + $this.val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. Well, at least it solved my issue.

I just used the .focus() function and now once I focus it adds @ then I can type.